# Gate Driver Not Working as Expected. Why?

Tags: power, mosfet, pcb, buck, driver

I am using the [ADuM5230 gate driver](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/ADuM5230-879060.pdf) to drive an N-channel MOSFET in a basic buck converter circuit that will convert a 12V DC input to a 5V DC output. The buck converter will operate at a 10kHz frequency and is to drive a 10 ohm load.

Block Diagram of ADuM5230:

[image]

The schematic of the converter on Proteus software:

[image]

1. Capacitors according to datasheet (tantalum & ceramic).
2. Three-Pin [schottky](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/SDT20100CT-SDT20100CTFP-1114657.pdf).
3. Used this [MOSFET](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/stp130n8f7-1156313.pdf).
4. Supplied 5V on Pin 2 and PWM signal on Pin 5, from power supply and signal generator respectively. I will use a micro controller in the future.

When I built the above circuit on a breadboard, I saw a 5V output across the load, as expected. Capacitor values are 10uF and 100nF as specified.

However, when I came to test the circuit on the PCB schematic provided below, the driver only produced 5V between the Viso and GNDiso pins (15 and 14) instead of 15V. The gate driver proceeded to heat up extremely quickly and somehow pulled more than 3A from the power supply. What am I doing wrong here?

PCB layout:

[image]

Track width is T50 and T20, while via size is T70.

Any ideas or suggestions on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Gate drivers aren't meant to be used for BJTs.

Comment: Applications of this particular gate driver are specifically MOSFET's and IGBT's

Comment: Yes. Your schematic shows BJTs.

Comment: Oh, Right! Will edit. That is the FET I provided later. The only reason I did that was due to matching PCB packages.

Comment: Well, the first problem that sticks out to me, then, is that you've got an inductor between your FET and your gate driver. That trace on the PCB should be as short as you can possibly make it, and it really shouldn't be going through any vias if you can avoid it.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed an improvement, but the problem seems to stem beforehand. If I am supplying 5V to the driver, (as shown in the datasheet) the internal DC-DC converter should output 15V between pins 15 and 14, which is not the case. This was tested successfully on a breadboard.

Comment: You appear to have a connection between pins 12 and 13. Is that maybe the problem? Those pins are marked DNC.

Comment: I actually connected both DNC pins together. Thinking about it, that is rather silly. However I doubt that this is causing the issue(?) Proteus software was indicating a missing connection between the two pins, and so I proceeded with the connection.

Comment: If the datasheet says not to connect some pins, don't connect the pins. Try cutting that trace on the board and see if that fixes your problem, though you may have blown your gate driver.

Comment: It could easily be causing the problem. Cut the connection.

Comment: I can confirm that I did not even solder pins 12 and 13 on the actual PCB. Everything else is as shown in the layout.

Comment: Pins resting on copper pads is still an electrical connection, just not a very good one.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will proceed to cut the tracks. Just to clarify that they are resting on the copper pads but not soldered.

Comment: Are Vdd1 and GND1 on pins 7 & 8 really unconnected? I know VDD1 and GND1 are also on pins 1 & 2 but that doesn't necessarily mean you can leave 7 & 8 unconnected. Likewise check the other side's connections.

Comment: They are indeed connected. This is shown in the PCB schematic where top copper traces are seen to connect Vdd1 and GND1 pins. However, I will edit the schematic to avoid confusion. I do not think I need to connect pins 9 - 11 since they are used for the channel B operation. Pin 4 was left unconnected in the PCB layout as this was not necessary for the correct operation of the driver in the test circuits previously built. I can easily make a quick connection and test. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe nothing to do with your problem, but why do you have 2 components with reference designator "R1", one of them appearing to be a capacitor?  Could it be you have a resistor in that spot though? If it was low enough value it could cause the problem.

Comment: John D, thanks for taking the time to go through the question, and you are absolutely correct. Unfortunately that was done due to PCB package sizes which need to be the same. The ceramic 100nF and 100 ohm SMD resistors I have are exactly the same size, so for convenience I used the same package in the layout. Will edit question. Apologies if that caused any confusion.

Comment: OK, and you're sure you don't have the resistor and capacitor interchanged?

Comment: Yes, I have two capacitors on each side (4 total). Two 10uF and two 100nF. The only resistor is 100 ohms on pin 16.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the part? Could be it was damaged by ESD or excessive heat during soldering.  Or does this happen on multiple PCBs?

Comment: No, only tested one PCB. That is the next logical step. Replacing the gate driver...